# Modelling Soil in a Scale Model

Tags: modeling, geotechnical-engineering, surface-modelling, soil-mechanics

I'm building a scale model for a proposed construction project.

Is it possible to simulate foundations operating in soil in a scale model?  What do people typically use?

Comment: There are a lot of research articles that do exactly what you have proposed. The topic is quite large. Have you done any background research from the scholarly articles available?

Comment: No - I don't know where to even start.

Answer (score 1):

Modeling soil behavior in a scaled-down lab system requires that the force of gravity be scaled up to maintain dynamic similitude. This requires the scaled system to be spun in a centrifuge at a speed which is mathematically derived from the linear scale-down factor.

As pointed out by ShadowMan, there is an extensive literature on scaled modeling of soil behavior in response to, for example, earthquake loading.